# Is there any reference about the roles of Michael Keaton and Ben Affleck in the upcoming 2023 film, The Flash?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, the-flash-2023

I've read that both actors would be part of *The Flash* (2023). Is there any reference which tells about whether both of them have a cameo in this movie or if they have an important extended role?

Comment: This question should have been closed long ago as *future works*.   Now that the movie is out, the question is entirely pointless.

Comment: Voting to reopen as per the close reason: "_Please check whether the work being asked about has been released since this question's closure, and vote to reopen if so._"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding Affleck's Batman, the director told [Variety](https://www.vanityfair.com/hollywood/2020/08/ben-affleck-returns-batman-the-flash-multiverse-keaton):

> He’s a very substantial part of the emotional impact of the movie.

Regarding Keaton's Batman, I wasn't able to find much. It seems that [he will](https://www.thewrap.com/michael-keaton-confirmed-batman-the-flash/) still appear in the film, despite earlier voicing concerns over covid.

Answer (score 2):

[*The Flash*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Flash_(film)) (2023) has already been released, and both of those actors were in the film. They also appeared in the [trailers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jprhe-cWKGs) before the film came out. Keaton had a significant role as Bruce Wayne / Batman, reprising his character from the Tim Burton films *Batman* (1989) and *Batman Returns* (1992). Affleck also appeared as Bruce Wayne / Batman, reprising his role from previous DCEU films.

[image: Affleck] [image: Keaton]

[image: Keaton] [image: Keaton]